# Django display paragraph if nothing found

Tags: html, django, templates, if-statement

I want that a message gets displayd if no search results are found but somewho im doing it wrong! Is

> if post in object_list.count == 0

unsuitable?

My Django template:

```
{% extends 'quickblog/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    {%  if post in object_list.count == 0 %}
        <p>No results, sorry :(</p>
        {% else %}
    {% for post in object_list %}
        <div class="post">
            <h1><u><a href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a></u></h1>
            <p>{{ post.content|linebreaksbr }}</p>
            <div class="date">
                <a>Published by: {{ post.author }}</a><br>
                <a>Published at: {{ post.published_date }}</a><br>
                <a>Category: {{ post.category }}</a><br>
                <a>Tag(s): {{ post.tag }}</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
```

Comment: Why are you using `if post in object_list.count` .
Try to use `{% if object_list.count == 0 %}`

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick ;) I thought i first had to check the object_list, my bad.

Comment: You do, but you were using improper syntax.